# Can I use an RPC to switch the Tezos node to another protocol?

Tags: protocol, protocol-hash

What is the command line command or RPC call for switching a Tezos node onto  one of the protocol amendments being voted on?

During which phases is it possible to switch to a candidate protocol.

Is it possible to do it during the proposal period?

Answer (score 1):

When (if) we move into the "Testing period" the chain is automatically forked. No action required, except for bakers. Bakers need to fire up "test-bakers" for the test-chain with a different "PROTOCOL" parameter.

If you want to send transaction or query the test chain during the testing period replace `main` with `test` for your RPC calls or add `--chain test` param to cli calls.

```
/chains/main/blocks/head <- main chain head
/chains/test/blocks/head <- test chain head
```

If you want you can always manually pull the amendment tarball and build with the changes. The node would however not be able to interact with the main network afaik.