# Why does querying tezos-node for test chain return 404?

Tags: protocol, protocol-hash

I am querying a mainnet tezos node for test chain data using the url specified in the following question:
[Can I use an RPC to switch the Tezos node to another protocol?](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/937/can-i-use-an-rpc-to-switch-the-tezos-node-to-another-protocol/940#940)

Specifically "/chains/test/blocks/head", this returns a 404.  This leads to several other questions(please assume archive mode unless explicitly stated):

1. does the binary for the tezos-node have to be the latest one?, if so, will I have to resync or will the latest binary be compatible with the current db?
2. if binary needs to be updated to see the test chain data, does archive mode need to be reestablished?
3. Is the test chain going to appear on alphanet?
4. If binary doesn't need to be updated, then why does it return a 404 error when I query for "/chains/test/blocks/head", please keep in mind, that url is from the previous question asked.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I wish someone would answer - I get same exact 404 error on that RPC, though if I use main instead of test it works.  I also just yesterday compiled the mainnet and am running the node with the --enable-testchain option, so im not sure what we are doing wrong here